# How to show only the checkmark selection without the selection of entire UITableViewCell in edit mode of UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, edit-tableview

I have a TableView with custom UITableViewCells. I have **UILongPressGestureRecognizer** enabled for my tableview cells. On long tap of gesture recognizers, I wanted to edit my tableview. Now in the edit mode of the tableview, all the cells that are selected are getting selected along with the accessory checkmark button. I want only the accessory checkmark button to be selected and not the entire cell. I tried multiple options like setting the selectionStyle property of the cell as **UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone** . In this case i am not able to select the cells in edit mode.

[image]

```
-(void)addLongPressGestureRecognizerForCell:(UITableViewCell *)tableViewCell{

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lLongPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureFunction:)];
    lLongPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.3;
    lLongPressGesture.delegate = self;
    [tableViewCell addGestureRecognizer:lLongPressGesture];
    [lLongPressGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
}
```

How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: post code of your recognizer method

Comment: Maybe modify the delegate calls and manually change the selection style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Got the Answer!!!!

All I need was to override the **setSelected** method and change the **selectedBackgroundView** for my tableViewCell in my custom tableViewCell class.

First i have added the backgroundview for my tableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
lCell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Next i have overridden the **setSelected** method as mentioned below.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state

UIImageView *lBalloonView = [self viewWithTag:102];
[lBalloonView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor hs_globalTint] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2]];

UITextView *lMessageTextView = [self viewWithTag:103];
lMessageTextView.backgroundColor    = [UIColor clearColor];

UILabel *lTimeLabel = [self viewWithTag:104];
lTimeLabel.backgroundColor  = [UIColor clearColor];

}
```

Also one of the most important point to be noted is to change the tableViewCell selection style.

```
lTableViewCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi - How you change the colour of the checked circles on the left side to a different colour in swift? Thanks

Comment: @SiphoKoza change the cell's tint colour to the colour you need for checked circle.

Comment: @Sree Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution—and one that doesn't require changing the background to gray—is to set the `multipleSelectionBackgroundView` of your `UITableViewCell` to a clear box.

In Swift:

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Hide selection box in multi-select mode.
    multipleSelectionBackgroundView = UIView()
    multipleSelectionBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

In Objective-C:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // Hide selection box in multi-select mode.
    self.multipleSelectionBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.multipleSelectionBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```